# What is the antonym of "toward"?

Tags: prepositions

I know the antonym of "to" is "from".

> 1. He went to the station.
> 2. He came from the station.

I am searching for a preposition opposite in meaning to "toward", but I could not find it, so I use "side" as follows:

> 3. He went toward the station.
> 4. He came from the station side.

Is there any preposition opposite in meaning to "toward"?

Comment: This is _not_ an answer to your question, but if you're wondering why there isn't just a single word that's an antonym of toward---there used to be, but it fell out of use (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/froward#English) and is completely archaic. Don't ever use it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this qualifies as a preposition, but if your aim is to express only the person’s *direction* of travel, and not where they are traveling to or from, then you could change #4 to:

> 4. He came from the direction of the station.

Given that aim, however, note that #3 can also be read as suggesting more than just direction. Your "went toward” isn't as emphatic as "went to", but it does still hint at the station being the person's destination. If you want to make it clearer that they are merely traveling in that direction, then #3 might be better changed as well, to something like:

> 3. He went in the direction of the station.

Comment: It seems you misunderstand my question .  I would like to use "come" not "go" in the second sentence.

Comment: "He came away from the station" is fine too.

Comment: I think using "from " means that he departed from the station.  I don't want to specify the departure point...I want only to describe the direction from which he came.

Comment: Ah, OK. I’ll change my answer accordingly. Note, however, that if you want to indicate direction only, and not source or destination, then “came from” isn’t ideal either, since it could imply that the starting point was the station. For completeness, I’ll mention that too.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of *toward X* is usually *away from X*.

> He went toward the station.

> He went away from the station.

This works with *come*:

> He came toward the station side.

> He came away from the station side.

Note that:

*X goes toward Y* and *X comes toward Y* will mean that at the end, X will be *closer* to Y but not necessarily *at* Y.

*X goes away from Y* and *X comes away from Y* will mean that at the end, X will be *further* from Y but not necessarily completely out of the sight of Y.